# Scrolling and zooming GtkDrawingArea with GtkScrolledWindow consumes a lot of memory and causes the application to crash

Tags: drawing, scale, zoom-sdk, gtk4

Is it possible to zoom (scale) the content of GtkDrawingArea and scroll it with GtkScrolledWindow without changing the drawing area size? My strategy was to use ViewPort and manually adjust the upper horizontal and vertical adjustments to match the content's size. This is useless. It only works if the line gtk widget set size request(area, w * scale, h * scale); is employed in the leftPressed function. In this case, however, the application consumes a large amount of memory and eventually crashes.

To demonstrate, the following code employs left mouse clicks to increase scale (zoom). The application's memory requirements quickly exceed 1GB, and the application crashes.

The question is whether there is a way to scale and scroll the content of the drawing area without resizing it. Such an approach would be much smoother (since it wouldn't require large buffer allocations). Such an approach would be much smoother (because it would not necessitate large buffer allocations).

The example code is written in C and employs GTK 4.6.7. It has been tested on Mac OS X Monterey and Windows 10. In both cases, the application stops responding and crashes after 6-7 left mouse clicks. The use of memory can be easily tracked in activity monitor on a Mac or task manager on a Windows computer.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget* vp, *sw;
double scale = 1;
int w = 500, h = 300;
GtkAdjustment* ha, * va;

static void leftPressed(GtkGestureClick* gesture, int n_press, double x, double y, GtkWidget* area)
{
    
    scale *= 2;
    //zooming should work by setting upper value only, without changing size of drawing area
    gtk_adjustment_set_upper(ha, w * scale);
    gtk_adjustment_set_upper(va, h * scale);

    gtk_widget_set_size_request(area, w * scale, h * scale);
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(area);
}

static void rightPressed(GtkGestureClick* gesture, int n_press, double x, double y, GtkWidget* area)
{
    scale /= 2;

    //gtk_widget_set_size_request(child, w / scale, h / scale);
    gtk_adjustment_set_upper(ha, w / scale);
    gtk_adjustment_set_upper(va, h / scale);
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(area);
}

static void drawRectangles(GtkDrawingArea* drawingarea, cairo_t* cr, int width, int height, gpointer data)
{
    cairo_scale(cr, scale, scale);
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 0, 0);
    cairo_rectangle(cr, 0, 0, 100, 50);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 1, 0);
    cairo_rectangle(cr, 200, 100, 100, 50);
    cairo_fill(cr);

    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 1);
    cairo_rectangle(cr, 400, 250, 100, 50);
    cairo_fill(cr);

}

static void createWindow(GtkApplication* app, gpointer data)
{
    GtkWidget* window = gtk_application_window_new(app);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 200);

    //Drawing Area
    GtkWidget* area = gtk_drawing_area_new();
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(area, w, h);
    gtk_drawing_area_set_draw_func(GTK_DRAWING_AREA(area), drawRectangles, NULL, NULL);

    //viewport
    //ha = gtk_adjustment_new();
    ha = gtk_adjustment_new(0, 0, w, 30, 360, 400);
    va = gtk_adjustment_new(0, 0, h, 20, 180, 200);
    vp = gtk_viewport_new(ha, va);
    gtk_viewport_set_child(GTK_VIEWPORT(vp), area);

    //Scrolled Window
    sw = gtk_scrolled_window_new();
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sw), GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_child(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sw), vp);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_max_content_height(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sw), 4000);
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_max_content_width(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sw), 4000);

    ha = gtk_scrolled_window_get_hadjustment(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sw));
    va = gtk_scrolled_window_get_vadjustment(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sw));

    //GtkGesture
    GtkGesture* pressElement = gtk_gesture_click_new();
    gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(pressElement), GDK_BUTTON_PRIMARY);
    gtk_widget_add_controller(area, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(pressElement));
    g_signal_connect(pressElement, "pressed", G_CALLBACK(leftPressed), area);

    GtkGesture* pressElement2 = gtk_gesture_click_new();
    gtk_gesture_single_set_button(GTK_GESTURE_SINGLE(pressElement2), GDK_BUTTON_SECONDARY);
    gtk_widget_add_controller(area, GTK_EVENT_CONTROLLER(pressElement2));
    g_signal_connect(pressElement2, "pressed", G_CALLBACK(rightPressed), area);

    gtk_window_set_child(GTK_WINDOW(window), sw);
    gtk_window_present(GTK_WINDOW(window));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
    // Create a new application
    GtkApplication* app = gtk_application_new("com.example.GtkApplication", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect(app, "activate", G_CALLBACK(createWindow), NULL);
    return g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);
}
```